# My files are writeable, why am I seeing filesize() and fread() errors?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert an image from my server as a background image converted to base64.

I receive these errors:

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed
>
> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

I have read that both errors can be caused by the files not being writeable, but I have made all files related writeable (the image file, the folder it is in and the file the code is on) and still no joy.

This is the php code

```
<?php
$img_source = "image.jpg";
$img_binary = fread(fopen($img_source, "r"), filesize($img_source));
$img_string = base64_encode($img_binary);
?>
```

And here is my css/php

```
body { background-image:url('data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo $img_string; ?>');
```

I was previously achiving the result I wanted by using **get_file_contents** but it was very very slow. This was my old method.

```
<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_url.'/'.$image)) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `file_get_contents` you were on the right track but it seems you were actually using the URL, not just the file path (thus `file_get_contents` used HTTP to get the file contents). Try changing it to this:

```
<?php
$img_source = "image.jpg";
$img_string = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_source));
?>
```

Comment: The `filesize()` error probably comes from the fact that the file path is not correct. You better double-check that.

Comment: $img_source = "image.jpg"; was misleading from me, sorry. I actually do need to use $img_source = $img_url.'/'.$image; as the image is never constant. I just used image.jpg for simplify my demo. I am trying to avoid file_get_contents though because it's slow

Comment: Where is the file? On your server?

Comment: Then you need to change `$img_url` so that it *does not* contain `http://` but the local path on the server (for example `./` or `../img` or `__DIR__."img"`), then `file_get_contents` will be fast.